# Direct proof that if mn is odd then m is odd and n is odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fake-proofs

I found the converse [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1691039/prove-that-if-m-and-n-are-any-two-odd-integers-then-mn-is-also-odd), although that's not what I want.

I have thought of a proof by contradiction and by contraposition, although I can't seem to figure out a way to finish a direct proof.

$mn = 2a + 1
$

If $a = 2kj + (k+j)$ for integers $k$ and $j$, which I got out of my crystal ball, then $mn = 4kj + 2(k+j) + 1$ and $mn = (2k + 1)(2j + 1)$, but then I have to prove that it's possible to write any integer $a$ as $2kj + (k + j)$, which I don't know how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you are overthinking this problem.  Try stating the *contrapositive* of the statement.  Also, for future reference, please include the problem statement in the body of your Questions, not relying wholly on the title for this important information.

Comment: Why must you have a *direct* proof? Proof by contraposition is far and away the easiest way to go.

Comment: I don't think showing that $a=2kj+(k+j)$ will really help; you would then be saying that since $mn=(2k+1)(2j+1)$, then $m=2k+1$ and $n=2j+1$, which is not necessarily true. ... I'm not really sure that a direct proof *is* possible.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow : This might be a homework assignment, where a direct proof must be done.

Comment: The proof by contraposition can easily be turned into a direct proof. Just divide $m$ by $2$ with remainder: $m = 2q + r$, where $r \in \left\{0,1\right\}$. Now distinguish between the cases $r=0$ (easy to derive a contradiction from) and $r=1$ (win).

Comment: It was on a test I had a few weeks ago. I can't believe how easy the answer was. (!)

Answer (score 5):

Write $m=2k+a$, where $a=0$ or $1$.

Write $n=2l+b$, where $b=0$ or $1$.

$mn=(2k+a)(2l+b)=4kl+2kb+2al+ab$

Since $mn$ is odd, $ab=1$, which means $a=1$ and $b=1$.